# Delete 2 Rows and 2 Columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

My code is below. I want to delete Rows 81 and 82 and columns F and H. My code below successfully deletes the rows but fails to delete the 2 columns. This with block is within a larger Sub.

```
With Sheets("PDEL_Report 500K")
    Rows("81:82").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("F:F,H:H").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Sheets("PDEL_Report 500K")
    .Rows("81:82").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft 'delete H first so shift does not affect current column F
    .Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
With Sheets("PDEL_Report 500K")
    .Rows("81:82").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With
```